# "do something" when an image is near another

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, uiimageview, pixel

I have two image (image1 and image2). Image 2 is moving around the screen. I want to "do something" when image 2 is near (20pixels) of image1. How can I do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a frame that adds 20 pixel to each side of your image1's frame:

```
CGRect image1Frame = image1.frame;
CGRect collisionFrame = CGRectMake(image1Frame.origin.x-20.0, image1Frame.origin.y-20.0, image1Frame.size.width+20.0, image1Frame.size.height+20.0);
```

Then just check if the frame of image2 collides with collisionFrame:

```
CGRectIntersectsRect(image2.frame, collisionFrame);
```

Answer (score 2):

Image 2 can't move unless something in your app moves it. Find the place in your code where you move image 2, and then do one of the following, or something similar:

1. Compute the distance to image 1 and take appropriate action if less than 20 pixels.
2. Send a message to the object that cares about the distance between images 1 and 2.
3. Post a notification informing any objects that care that image 2 has moved.
4. Set a flag saying that image 2 has moved, and make sure some other part of your app periodically checks the flag and does the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to creating a CGRect with the current size of the Image + 21 pixels, create a CGRect of the other Image and then use:

```
 CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRect1, CGRect2)
```